# What is an HTTPS Interception Certificate and can schools monitor devices through it?

Tags: tls, wifi, monitoring

My school (UK) recently sent out a message to all of us.

> "In order to provide the best standard of online safety we are
> improving the quality of internet filtering and monitoring on our
> school network."
>
> The new system requires installation of a “certificate” on any device
> (laptop, phone, tablet etc) connecting to the school Wi-Fi.  We have
> already installed this on L4, U4 and L5 school-provided iPads but we
> are not able to do this on your own device(s).
>
> If you do not perform the necessary steps, you will receive numerous
> warnings/errors when attempting to browse the web."

I have my own personal iPad, but I don’t want to install the HTTPS Interception Certificate until I know I’m not going to be monitored with it. What is it exactly? If I install it on my iPad, is it permanent? Could I use VPN instead to access the Internet instead of having to install the certificate to use the Wi-Fi? Since I’m a full boarder here, I can’t exactly have the relief of going home and using my own Wi-Fi. If I disconnect from the school Wi-Fi and return to my country, would the school still be able to monitor my device and search history?

Comment: As the duplicate mentions, the certificate is only relevant on their network. No certificate is permanent. You can't use VPN on a network that you can't use.